# gcloud beta projects move some-project-id --organization=0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

We created a project in the Google Cloud Console and it added it to an organization.  We need to move this project to another organization where our other projects are.

We are trying to move it with this gcloud command but we get an error.

`$ gcloud beta projects move some-project-id --organization=0`

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.projects.move) INVALID_ARGUMENT: field [Project.parent] has issue [Project parent cannot be empty.]
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Project parent cannot be empty.
    field: Project.parent`

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/projects/move

Comment: can you share the command line you used?

Comment: Thank you, I had it in the subject but not the body of the stack overflow post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for the move command:

> This command can fail for the following reasons:
>   -... 
>   - the given project is already in an organization.

Indeed, from [the migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing):

> Project migration isn't reversible. After a project is associated with an organization, you can't change it back to "no organization" or move it to another organization on your own. To change the organization a project is associated with, you'll need to be a G Suite or Cloud Premium customer with a support package.

Comment: @chmoder Supporting to Oliver's answer, If you are having a [premium support](https://cloud.google.com/support/?options=premium-support#support-options) plan, you can request for the removal of your current organization from the project. After removing the Organization, you can migrate your project into the new Organization by following [this](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) documentation