# Migrating a project between organizations in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

so we created a project within the wrong organization on google cloud platform. and i was wondering if there is anyway to migrate this project to the right organization or to make the organization a sub organization of the right one.

Thanks

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992749/4926605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gcloud beta projects move some-project-id --organization=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49987351/gcloud-beta-projects-move-some-project-id-organization-0)